# (k)-nearest neighbo(u)r tags

Tags: support, tags

We now have tags 'k-nearest-neighbor' and 'nearest-neighbour'. I'm not familiar enough with this particular branch of statistics to be sure whether they mean more-or-less the same thing. There's also the American-British spelling thing - I don't know how we deal with that either. Merge? Synonyms? Does either/any solution require an admin or user with >10k rep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same thing. I've done the merge and maintained the spelling on the original k-NN tag. There should not be a need for a synonym here as anyone typing "nearest" will have the existing tag show up as a suggestion.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks Rob.